# How to create a clickable Listview and go to new page where the user can add items within the list

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, listview, android-activity

I would like some guidance on how to create a clickable Listview and go to new page where the user can add items within the list as I am creating a To Do List, and I want the user to be able to create multiple lists, and then tap the list, and enter multiple items within that very list.

Thanks.

**UPDATE - Added .java code for reference. This may explain what I have implemented thus far better than the text above.**

```
public class ActionBarMenuDemoActivity extends SherlockListActivity {
private static final String[] items = {  };
private ArrayList<String> words = null;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    initAdapter();
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.option, menu);

    EditText add = null;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        View v = menu.findItem(R.id.add).getActionView();

        if (v != null) {
            add = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        }
    }

    if (add != null) {
        add.setOnEditorActionListener(onSearch);
    }

    return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}

public void onCreateContextMenu(Menu menu, View v,
        ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.context, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.add:
        add();
        break;
    case R.id.preferences:
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SettingsActivity.class));
        break;
    }

    return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}


@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) getListAdapter();

    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    if (itemId == R.id.cap) {
        String input = words.get(info.position);
        input = input.toUpperCase();
        adapter.remove(words.get(info.position));
        adapter.insert(input, info.position);
        return (true);
    }

    return (super.onContextItemSelected(item));
}

private void initAdapter() {
    words = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String s : items) {
        words.add(s);
    }

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, words));
}

private void add() {
    final View addView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add, null);

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Add a List").setView(addView)
            .setPositiveButton("Create", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    addWord((TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.title));
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).show();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void addWord(TextView title) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) getListAdapter();

    adapter.add(title.getText().toString());
    Toast.makeText(ActionBarMenuDemoActivity.this,
            title.getText().toString() + " Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();

    title.setText("");
}

private TextView.OnEditorActionListener onSearch = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event == null || event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            addWord(v);

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }

        return (true);
    }
};
      }
```

Some of this code will be removed, as I used a tutorial as my starting point.

Comment: Create an Activity to display a List, you need to have two adapters: One to display the lists, one for the todo-items. After selecting an Item in the first list, load the todo-items and display them using your todo-adapter...

Comment: to create listview & adapter http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews  ...or post you code where u r facing prob ?

Comment: Michael, thank you very much for your response. Could you expand and explain how I could go about doing this, or if possible provide some the framework of the code that I could amend so that I have a better understanding. I will add my main activity code to the original post now - this may help you to understand what I have done thus far.